Intermittent Perfromance with AWS API Gateway websocket- Lambda postToConnection
Hello Fellow Stackers!
I am finally resorting to ask here:
I have a Lambda (Node 20.X) which is triggered by an SNS message. The of the message contains a connection ID.
The Lambda needs to identify all players and their connections and send the game object.
It does send a message, but not always... most of the times the client.send invocation, fails silently - which is the frustrating thing!
Here is the code:
import {
  ApiGatewayManagementApiClient,
  PostToConnectionCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-apigatewaymanagementapi";


export const handler = async (event) => {
  const ws_url = process.env.ws_url;
  const client = new ApiGatewayManagementApiClient({ endpoint: ws_url });

  const Game = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].Sns.Message);
  switch (Game.type) {
    case 'game':
      wsMessage(client, Game.data);
      break;
    default:
      console.error('Unknown Message Type', Game.type, 'Message', Game);
  }

  const response = { statusCode: 200 };
  return response;
};
const wsMessage = async (client, Game) => {
  if (!Game.hasOwnProperty('players')) return console.error('No Players in Game', Game);
  const sendings = [];
  if (Game.players.length > 0) {
    try {
      for (const player of Game.players) {
        console.log('connection_id', player.connection_id);
        if (!player.hasOwnProperty('connection_id') || !player.connection_id) continue;
        const requestParams = {
          ConnectionId: player.connection_id,
          // Data: JSON.stringify({ type: "game", "data": Game }),
          Data: JSON.stringify({ type: "game", "data": Game.id }),
        };
        console.log('player', player, requestParams);

        const command = new PostToConnectionCommand(requestParams);
        console.log("Sending", requestParams);

        // sendings.push(client.send(command).then((r) => { console.log("Sent", r); return r; }).catch((e) => { console.error("Send Error", e.message); }));
        await client.send(command).then((r) => { console.log("Sent", r); return r; }).catch((e) => { console.error("Send Error", e.message); });
      }
      // if (sendings.length > 0) await Promise.all(sendings);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("WS Sending error", error.message, error.stack);
    }
  } else console.error('No Players in ', Game.id);
}

You will notice I have tried to reduce the message size - tried Promise.all as well to speed up the sending all to no avail. It sometimes sends the response to the web-socket and most of the times fails silently - i.e. does not deliver the message, and the console log does not show the result or any errors.
I am properly stuck. Any help and ideas?

After some more thinking and coffee and then some more thinking - as well as consulting previous experience for the n-th time: I seem to have gotten me unstuck - the function is set as async - I added an await in front of it and it all worked...
